# Rxswift PublishRelay.flatMapLatest with networking call, but no response

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I'm new to Rxswift Here is my View Model code:

```
    let test = reloadRelay
        .asObservable()
        //2
        .flatMapLatest({ apiClient.requestData(type: rankingType) })
        .map({ $0.results })
        .asDriver { (error) -> Driver<[ArticleResult]> in
            errorRelay.accept((error as? ErrorResult)?.localizedDescription ?? error.localizedDescription)
            return Driver.just([])
    }
```

This is very typical and simple ViewModel with logics to get data and send the View layer.
However, when I initialise the ViewModel. The networking call (2) never happened.

Here is my networking code:

```
    func requestData(type: ArticlesRankingType) -> Observable<Articles> {
    let urlString = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/mostpopular/v2/\(type.rawValue)/7.json?api-key=dylOnQnYUzEF1B9MTYYHM0MyffMPBZRi"
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10)
    
    return Observable.create { observer in
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                observer.onError(error)
                return
            }
            
            if let data = data ,let responseCode = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    
                    if responseCode.statusCode == 200 {
                        let value = try decoder.decode(Articles.self, from: data)
                        return observer.onNext(value)
                    }
                }
                catch let parseJSONError {
                    observer.onError(error!)
                    print("error on parsing request to JSON : \(parseJSONError)")
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        return Disposables.create {
            task.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I call my output in View:

```
 articlesViewModel.output
        .articles.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])
        .drive(tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "aCell", cellType: ArticlesCell.self))
 articlesViewModel
 .input
 .reload
 .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: ())
 .drive()
```

Can someone tell what's wrong with my code? Thanks

Comment: Observables, and Drivers, are lazy. They don't do anything until and unless they are subscribed to. Did you subscribe to the Driver? (I.E., did you call `.drive`?)

Comment: Also, URLSession already has an Rx wrapper in the library. No need to roll your own. `URLSession.shared.rx.data(request: urlRequest)`

Comment: @DanielT. Thanks for your remind I have solved the problem, it seems you have to subscribe the Driver and subscribe the output as well before starting the data flow.

Comment: An FYI... Having an empty drive function (`.drive()`) is a code smell. Why are you activating the driver if you aren't using the results?

Comment: @DanielT. Thanks for your correction, I have figured it out and write an article. Please read this and feel free to give any advice! Thanks!  https://medium.com/dev-genius/rxswift-mvvm-understand-your-viewmodel-50e8fe12436b